# Unable to display contents of Session to ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, session

So I have a piece of code which, when a user logs in, will take their username and put it into a Session, called username. (For the sake of simplicity I've just put a test string in there but normally it would be userEmail.Username)

```
 else
            {
                Session["Username"] = "test";
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

            }
```

As far as I can tell, this chunk of code works, as once the user logs in they do get redirected to default.aspx. I also have another piece of code (in the Master page's code behind on Page_Load) which makes one panel visible if the session is NOT null, which also works, meaning there IS something stored in the session:

```
  if (Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            pnlLoggedIn.Visible = Visible;

        }
```

However when I try to display this in front of the text:

```
 <h3>Welcome back <h3>
```

So it would say "Welcome back [username]" I can't. I probably just don't know the code. I've tried creating a public string called getUsername and calling that, I've tried putting Session["Username"] in front but it just prints out that, what is the code I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<h3>Welcome back <%= Server.HtmlEncode((string)Session["Username"]) %><h3>
```

Comment: Two errors: #1 - Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' #2 - The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ah, I forgot Session items were objects, not strings. I added a `(string)` in front of that. Does the updated example work now?

Comment: That's fixed it, perfect! Can't believe ASP.net would make it so complex for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

In the markup you'd need a server-side code block to be processed before the page is rendered to the client.  Something like this:

```
<h3>Welcome back <%= Server.HtmlEncode(Session["Username"]) %></h3>
```

You could also encapsulate it in a page-level property to de-couple the UI code from the session a bit, something like this:

```
<h3>Welcome back <%= Server.HtmlEncode(Username) %></h3>
```

This would look for a property called `Username` on the page, which you can add to the code-behind:

```
protected string Username
{
    get { return Session["Username"]; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

always check `Not NULL` for `Session,ViweStates,etc`

#### Welcome back

```
protected string UserName
{
     string UName="";

     if(Session["Username"]!=NULL)
     UName=Session["Username"].ToString();

    get { return UName; }
}
```